# How to solve java import com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem?

Tags: java, nio, sun

I'm solving dependencies for an open source java project and I can't find to what jar this import belongs, maybe it's a special JDK it belongs to?

```
import com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem;
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Provide more detail about your question. But this looks like jdk issues, most likely you are running a non oracle jdk. com.sun.** should be from from oracle jdk

Comment: You would be doing the project a favor if you removed that import entirely.  [Here is the correct way](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) to create a FileSystem from a zip file.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I can see, `com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem` class was not part of the official Java SE libraries.

- In Java 6 and earlier, the class does not exists
- In Java 7 and Java 8, the class is in the "demo" suite.
- In Java 9 and later, the class is no longer present in the "demo" suite ... but there is now a class called `jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem` in the `jdk.zipfs` module.  However the class is not exposed by the module, and it is declared as package private.  You are supposed to access it using the `FileSystems.getFileSystem` method.

So to port your code to Java 9+, you need to add that module to your Java 9+ module dependencies (if your code is modular).  Then you remove the `ZipFileSystem` import and replace it with an import for `java.nio.FileSystem`.  Finally change your code get a `FileSystem` object by calling `FileSystems.getFileSystem` with a URI with the scheme `jar:`.

There is more information about the Zip Filesystem Provider in the Java SE documentation; e.g.

- [Zip File System Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html)
- [Module jdk.zipfs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.zipfs/module-summary.html)